# Regular Expressions: How to Express \w Without Underscore

Tags: php, regex, url

Is there a concise way to express:

```
\w but without _
```

That is, "all characters included in \w, except _"

I'm asking this because I'm looking for the most concise way to express domain name validation. A domain name may include lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, period signs and dashes, but no underscores. \w includes all of the above, plus an underscore. So, is there any way to "remove" an underscore from \w via regex syntax?

**Edited:** I'm asking about regex as used in PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the regex flavour. Which language are you using? The easiest way though would be to just use `[A-Za-z0-9]`. `\w` does (normally) **not** include dashes or periods.

Comment: Depending on the flavor `\w` may support Unicode characters. Unless you are totally sure about what `\w` represent, it is best that you use the character class `[]` and list all of them out normally.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

the following character class (in Perl)

```
[^\W_]
```

`\W` is the same as `[^\w]`

Comment: explain to me how it is not....and note that the `?:` part is just saying to not actually capture the group found by the atom

Comment: @protist: The atom is WRONG. `\w` will match `_`, and `|` is alternation and acts like OR, not AND

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it before. I'm using PHP. Would that work in PHP?

Comment: I am no expert on PHP, but a little research affirms that PHP does indeed have a `\W` as used in my Perl.  This will likely work for you as well.

Comment: So, do I understand this correctly, that [^\W_] is the same as [A-Za-z0-9.-]?

Comment: I am unsure as to whether `.` and `-` are included, as what is considered a `word` character differs slightly by locale.  Some sources say `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (but are sure to say this is not always true).  `[^\W_]` is `\w but without _`, though certainly.

Comment: very creative, Thanx 

Comment: To put it into words think: (not (not word) or underscore) where word is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 20):

You could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?!_)\w`

However, I think writing `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` is more readable.

Comment: That would be `(?!_)\w`, no?

Comment: Look-around is slower than normal matching. May not matter here, though

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Bergi - I have a question: wouldn't it be proper to write [a-zA-z0-9\.\-] - escaping period and dash – or is it wrong/unnecessary to escape them in this case? (I'm new to regex, and this may be a silly question...)

Comment: Not necessary: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. Only characters that have a special meaning in a character class (`]\^-`) need to be escaped, and not when unambigous.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Bergi! So, looking through the entire body of answers to my question, these solutions would all work: (?!_)\w --- [^\W_] --- or [A-Za-z0-9.-] --- am I right?

Comment: @Dimitri: Yes, depending on that `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]` in your regex flavour.

Comment: As an aside, apparently Powershell does not permit escaped underscores e.g. \_.  Just use the underscore on its own.  Keeps biting me...

Answer (score 5):

To be on the safe side, usually, we will use character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]
```

The regex "fragment" above match English alphabet, and digits, plus period `.` and dash `-`. It should work even with the most basic regex support.

Shorter may be better, but only if you know exactly what it represents.

I don't know what language you are using. In a lot of engines, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (some requires "ASCII mode" for this). However, some engine have Unicode support for regex, and may extend `\w` to match Unicode characters.

Comment: This will exclude all unicode characters like "äö" etc.

Comment: @MrD: Yup, the best way is not to use regex to do domain validation at all.

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is right `\w` means `[A-Za-z0-9_]` period signs, dashes are not included.

info: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes

so I guess what you want is `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`

Comment: The problems come with this when you have non-english letters.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási **domain name** ,  non-english letter?

Comment: @Kent - [ICANN approves non-Latin domain names](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-10387139-93.html).

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. However, AFAIK you can get a domain with accents nowadays (at least in Hungary).

Answer (score 2):

Some regex flavours have a negative lookbehind syntax you might use:

```
\w(?<!_)
```

Comment: Negative lookaheads are more widely supported than negative lookbehinds.

Comment: @JosephSilber True. Conceptually, I find "give me a word character ... but not an underscore" slightly easier than "the next thing I want shouldn't be an underscore ... otherwise, give me a word character" to follow, if negative lookbehinds *are* available, though.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking to match `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` can be written short as `[\W^_]+` (in Python)

However, micro performance might be worse because with `\W` first you match `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` and then you unmatch `_`.

```py
def camelCaseNotation(value):
    """Select all symbolic character plus the next alphabetical character. Remove symbols and uppercases the alphabetic character."""
    return re.sub(r"[\W^_]+([\w]{0,1})", lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [^_], and then think of what else characters I need to deny. If you need to filter a keyboard input, it's quite simple to enumerate all the unwanted characters.

Comment: This is a very poor approach. Domain name has a defined set of allowed characters, so white-listing can be done. When you black list, you need to care about what Unicode character you need to deny also.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I've taken into count that doamin names CAN have unicode characters (for example accented vowels). So I think it's quite hard to precisely form an ultimate correct white list solution.

Comment: There is specs for that - it is troublesome, but defined. People tend to forgot/overlook things when blacklisting.

Comment: I agree, that's why I mentioned if the case is a keyboard input, because that can simplify things IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
\([^\w]|_)\u
```

If you use preg_filter with this string any character in \w (excluding _ underscore) will be filtered.