# django regular expression only to match alphanumeric not underscore

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a model field where I want user only to enter alphanumeric character.
I have set regex like:

```
validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w]+$'
```

It also takes `_` but I only want to take `aplha numeric characters` not `_`.
What might be the regex for it ?

Answer (score 2):

We usually use a simple `[A-Za-z0-9]` regex which is essentially `\w` but without the underscore (assuming you are not setting any specific locales or a unicode flag):

> `\w`
>
> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore; **this is equivalent to the
>   set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`**. With `LOCALE`, it will match the set `[0-9_]` plus
>   whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current
>   locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[0-9_]` plus
>   whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

Also see [Regular Expressions: How to Express \w Without Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858346/regular-expressions-how-to-express-w-without-underscore) for other options.

Answer (score 2):

To disallow `_` with `\w`, you may use the opposite class `\W` (**non-word shorthand character class**) in a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and exclude a `_` by adding it to the negated character class:

```
r'^[^\W_]+$'
    ^^^^
```

This pattern matches start of string (`^`), one or more characters other than non-word chars (=matches all word chars) and other than `_` (so, all that are `\w` but excluding a `_`), and then the end of string.

Or (if you only work with ASCII) just use

```
r'(?i)^[a-z0-9]+$'
```

As `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` without the `re.UNICODE` flag.

The `(?i)^[a-z0-9]+$` matches both lower- and uppercase ASCII letters due to the case insensitive inline modifier `(?i)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

If you don't want uppercase avoid A-Z