# Regular expressions \w without underscore in a character set []

Tags: regex

This question is identical to [Regular Expressions: How to Express \w Without Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858346), except that the goal is to match characters in the letter (L) general category plus a specified set of additional characters.

For example, `[-$\a\d]+` would match identifiers like `$gâteau-Noël-19` but not `$gâteau_Noël-19`, if a hypothetical \a letter class existed.  But for some bizarre and incomprehensible reason it does not.

So the clumsy substitute suggested in the previous question, `[^\W_]`, works fine as a replacement for \a by itself.  But how can it be combined with additional characters to form the above regular expression?

Comment: What variety of regex are you using? PCRE?

Comment: Unicode property `\p{L}` matches any letter in any language, but it is not supported by all regex flavour.

Comment: Like `[\p{L}\d$-]+` https://regex101.com/r/9tfwVB/1

Comment: Python flavor - `\p` isn't supported directly, but it led to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595979/how-to-implement-pl-in-python-regex.  Thanks!